# How to filter and copy files with spaces in linux using grep

Tags: filter, grep, copy

I have huge data of of .zip file saved with spaces like below format

this is the result of **ls -altr** command

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  428236 Oct 27 12:58 'Tue Oct 27 10:57:31 2020-(889324)-(0109).zip'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201228 Oct 27 13:03 'Tue Oct 27 11:03:18 2020-(889023)-(010).zip'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  571468 Oct 27 13:25 'Tue Oct 27 11:25:07 2020-(889234)-(0101).zip'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70124 Oct 27 13:28 'Tue Oct 27 11:28:18 2020-(8823423)-(0100).zip'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1201484 Oct 27 13:33 'Tue Oct 27 11:31:56 2020-(8823423)-(010).zip'
```

I want to copy any file that contain 889 to a separate folder I am using below command that I found to get the job done

```
ls -lrt | awk '{ print $NF}' | egrep "889" | xargs -n1 -i cp  {} /home/test
```

This command is able to filer all files that contain 889 but not able to copy when I run command I get following error

```
cp: cannot stat '2020-(8892342)-(010).zip': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '2020-(188923)-(0102).zip': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '2020-(9889234)-(0109).zip': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '2020-(889234)-(010).zip': No such file or directory
```

I did a little google and someone was saying that is because my file names are long and with spaces. Would appreciate if someone can help me with a solution

Comment: How about `cp *889* /home/test` ?

Comment: this works in case if the file name is like 88934534534 but it also copy if a file is like 3453453889 basically what I need is if anything that starts with 889 should be copied only

Comment: `cp 889* /home/test` then, maybe?